# OpenCV haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml can't be found

Tags: c++, xml, opencv

It seems like there are a lot of people that have had this problem.
I can't seem to get my program to find haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml,
haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml IS in the current working directory, and every
other project directory at this point.
I have tried with both just "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml" AND "C:\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml" no luck. I made sure that it is "unblocked" in the properties, still nothing. Does anyone know how to get opencv to see haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml in windows 7 x64?
Thank you very much.

Comment: For OpenCV2.4.8, they should be located under "OpenCV-Dir\sources\data\haarcascades\".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me the "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml" is in the following directory:
C:\opencv2.4.9\sources\data\haarcascades

I am loading it with the following command:

`CascadeClassifier cascade1;
cascade1.load("C:/opencv2.4.9/sources/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");`

It seems to be working for me here when I give the exact path to the location of the file in win7 x64.

Another thing you can check is if your libraries are linked correctly(i.e: For debug/release mode, whichever one are you using)

Answer (score 7):

If you ever have an issue loading a particular cascade, I would head to the OpenCV GitHub and grab the one you want from the repo. You can then place the .xml file anywhere you want and then specify a relative or absolute path (your choice).

[OpenCV Cascade .xml Files](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades)